# Textbox alternative for UWP apps

Tags: c#, uwp

I am developing a text editor in C# UWP and since now, I always used the RichEditBox. I modified it to only allow unformatted text input and stuff like that. But the performance of larger text is a big issue. It also has the problem, that it won't render the text anymore if there are more than 8900 lines. So I tried using the [MonacoEditor for UWP](https://github.com/hawkerm/monaco-editor-uwp), which was way better in text-rendering but the startup performance was very weak. Then I found a control, called [CodeEditorControl](https://github.com/WelterDevelopment/CodeEditorContol-WinUI), which is based on the Win2d library, but It also has bad performance in rendering large amounts of text.

The new Editor for Windows 11 has a very performant control, but I really could not find anything about it. Maybe someone knows more about it?

**Is there any good control for UWP, which can handle a larger amount of text?**

Comment: Maybe you could try to custom a text control by yourself. Please check this sample: [CustomEditControl](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/CustomEditControl)

Comment: Yeah, I think, this is the only option. But I will try to build using the Win2D library. I will also create a Github repo for this and share this link here. Thank you :D